# Pattern recognition for youtube

Tags: discussion

Would [such question](https://superuser.com/questions/877415/pattern-recognition-for-youtube) could find place here?

> I am looking for software that would allow to match supplied image in
>   video frame. I plan to use it to data-mine Hearthstone videos to get
>   data on what decks are better.
>
> Couple of years ago I saw a guy (I think he's Ukrainian) to
>   demonstrate something similar. He would print screen live feed from
>   his web cam and then would cut part of image and then supply it to the
>   pattern recognition software he was running and it would apply border
>   on matching part on live feed while he was moving camera. It would
>   match it under certain angle. Since Hearthstone cards are always face
>   up it should be possible to reuse this. I tried looking for this video
>   and software without luck. If you know a peace of software that could
>   do something similar(with some tweaks perhaps) or other good idea how
>   to get my hands on Hearthstone game data please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No that would be definitely off-topic. That fits better on stackoverflow, data science or cross validated SE.

Comment: Thanks, I will try them.

Comment: To add to that, this is certainly a computer vision question and computer vision is not on topic as it is not video production related.